# Is it possible to do json transformation using jsonata for api's exposed via apache camel?

Tags: json, apache-camel, jsonpath, jackson-databind, jsonata

Similar to camel-jolt, looking for an integration of apache camel with **jsonata** [https://jsonata.org/]  query and transformation framework.  We need to expose Rest API's using apache camel and do json transformation using json query language [jsonata for eg] without doing binding to java objects, as the json structure is quite dynamic.

Answer (score 1):

Here is [JSONata Camel component](https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/jsonata-component.html) which integrates JSONata processing into Apache Camel.

Answer (score 0):

Camel support jsonpath expression. we can evaluate jsonpath expression [https://jsonpath.com/] without the need to unmarshal
json to java object. This will be very helpful when we need to apply transformation to downstream json, which is very dynamic
in nature.

```
import org.apache.camel.Exchange;
import org.apache.camel.Expression;
import org.apache.camel.spi.Language;

Language lan = exchange.getContext().resolveLanguage("jsonpath");
Expression exp = lan.createExpression("$.jsonRoot[?(@.jsonFieldx=='3.0.0')]");

List<?> jsonList = exp.evaluate(exchange, List.class);
```